# Cumulate count between date with 0 when there are records for a given day

Tags: postgresql

How could one write a Postgresql query that gives both daily and cumulative counts without gaps? E.g. if there is no data for a given day, it would show `0` as a daily count for that that day and the same cumulative sum as the previous day?

I think I'd need `GENERATE_SERIES`, but I don't know how to do it. I'm also not entirely sure if `order by day asc rows between unbounded preceding and current row` would work correctly always, but maybe not the biggest issue here.

I have tried to craft the query with `PARTITION BY` and

Let's say I write a table and add data such as

```
create table test
(
    id int4 NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,  
    data int4,  
    created_at timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
);

insert into test(data, created_at) values(1, '2021-04-01');
insert into test(data, created_at) values(2, '2021-04-01');
insert into test(data, created_at) values(3, '2021-04-02');
insert into test(data, created_at) values(4, '2021-04-03');
insert into test(data, created_at) values(5, '2021-04-05');
insert into test(data, created_at) values(6, '2021-04-07');
```

and then create a queries such as

```
SELECT
  created_at as "Date",
  count(1) as "Daily count"
FROM test
WHERE created_at >= '2021-04-01'
  AND created_at <= '2021-04-30'
GROUP BY 1
```

giving

| Date | Daily count |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-04-01 00:00:00 | 2 |
| 2021-04-02 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 2021-04-03 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 2021-04-05 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 2021-04-07 00:00:00 | 1 |

```
with data as (
  select
    date_trunc('day', created_at) as day,
    count(1)
  from test
  group by 1
)
select
  day,
  running_total(count) over (order by day asc rows between unbounded preceding and current row)
from data
```

| day | running_total |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-04-01 00:00:00 | 2 |
| 2021-04-02 00:00:00 | 3 |
| 2021-04-03 00:00:00 | 4 |
| 2021-04-05 00:00:00 | 5 |
| 2021-04-07 00:00:00 | 6 |

But as noted, how could these two be combined without gaps on daily values? Somehow it feels I get close but bump into some (syntax) problem. Maybe those two queries are the simplest and cleanest examples of what I'm thinking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You write in your question:

> `I think I'd need GENERATE_SERIES, but I don't know how to do it.`

Indeed you do - and you can as follows (all the code below is also given in the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=527a9dae65e0fe3d5640ce9fda912964)):

```
CREATE TABLE cal_tab (cal_date) AS
(
  SELECT  GENERATE_SERIES
  (
    '2021-04-01'::DATE,
    '2021-04-07'::DATE,
    '1 DAY'
  )
);
```

Just to check:

```
SELECT cal_date::DATE FROM cal_tab;
```

Result:

```
cal_date
2021-04-01
2021-04-02
2021-04-03
...
... snipped for brevity - you determine how many rows there are with the 
... second parameter to GENERATE_SERIES
...
```

Then, I use your data:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
    id         INT4 NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,  
    data       INT4,  
    created_at DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
);
```

Populate (slightly modified from the question - so as not to have the id the same as the provided data (i.e. 1...6), - instead, I explicitly inserted hundreds - improves legibility):

```
INSERT INTO test (data, created_at) VALUES (100, '2021-04-01');
INSERT INTO test (data, created_at) VALUES (100, '2021-04-01');

INSERT INTO test (data, created_at) VALUES (200, '2021-04-02');
INSERT INTO test (data, created_at) VALUES (300, '2021-04-03');
                                                               -- GAP for 4th of April
INSERT INTO test (data, created_at) VALUES (500, '2021-04-05');
                                                               -- GAP for 6th of April
INSERT INTO test (data, created_at) VALUES (600, '2021-04-07');
```

And then run the following SQL:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT  -- try with and without DISTINCT
  ct.cal_date::DATE,
  COALESCE(t.data, 0) AS data, -- t.created_at::DATE,
  
  COUNT(t.created_at) OVER (PARTITION BY t.created_at 
                              ORDER BY ct.cal_date ASC) AS "Cnt/day", 
  COUNT(t.created_at) OVER (ORDER BY ct.cal_date ASC) AS "Cum. cnt/day",
  
  SUM(t.data) OVER (ORDER BY ct.cal_date::DATE ASC) AS "Sum/day"
FROM 
  cal_tab ct
LEFT OUTER JOIN test t
  ON ct.cal_date = t.created_at::DATE
ORDER BY ct.cal_date::DATE ASC;
```

Result:

```
  cal_date  data    Cnt/day Cum. cnt/day  Cum. sum/day
2021-04-01  100           2            2           200
2021-04-02  200           1            3           400
2021-04-03  300           1            4           700
2021-04-04    0           0            4           700
2021-04-05  500           1            5          1200
2021-04-06    0           0            5          1200
2021-04-07  600           1            6          1800
```

A result which, I believe covers all your requested elements.

In this case, you don't have to worry about the FRAME clause (i.e. the `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`) bit - FRAMEs are a kind of sub-partitioning method - but the long phrase above is actually the default - see [here](https://www.compose.com/articles/metrics-maven-window-frames-in-postgresql/) for a good introduction to window frames in PostgreSQL.

You could also (depending on your requirements) use a CTE (Common Table Expression) for your query if you don't wish to create a permanent calendar table (see my answer [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/290939/34007) for an example of this). (+1 for having made me think!).