# Run calculation not working in sub query, "does not exist"

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

```
PostgreSQL 13.2 (Debian 13.2-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, 
compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
```

I have a query that provides the count of 2 things over 2 time periods:

- time period of this week, start of the week (Sunday/Monday midnight)
  -> today
- time period of last week, start of last week (Sunday/Monday midnight)
  -> today but last week

What I would like is to also perform a calculation on the two "car" count ints that are returned and provide this with the query result.

I can of course do this in the consuming app, but I'd love to be able to do it in my SQL.

### Working SQL

This is the base SQL and is what I currently have and **working**:

```
WITH last_week AS (
  SELECT COUNT(car_name) as car_count_last_week
  FROM car_store
  WHERE car_name = 'awesome'
  AND car_time >= date_trunc('week', CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 week')
  AND car_time <= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '6 days'
), current_week AS (
  SELECT COUNT(car_name) AS car_count_current_week
  FROM car_store
  WHERE car_name = 'awesome'
  AND car_time >= date_trunc('week', CURRENT_DATE)
  AND car_time <= CURRENT_DATE
)
SELECT car_name,
  date_trunc('week', CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 week') AS start_of_last_week,
  CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '6 days' AS today_but_last_week,
  date_trunc('week', CURRENT_DATE) AS start_of_current_week,
  CURRENT_DATE AS today,
  car_count_last_week,
  car_count_current_week
  FROM car_store
  CROSS JOIN last_week, current_week
  WHERE car_name = 'awesome'
  GROUP BY car_name, car_count_last_week, car_count_current_week
  ORDER BY car_name;
```

### Setup DB table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS car_store (
     car_id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
     car_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
     car_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY(car_id)
  )

INSERT INTO car_store(car_name, car_time) VALUES ('awesome', '2021-05-03 15:28:00.116594');
INSERT INTO car_store(car_name, car_time) VALUES ('awesome', '2021-05-11 16:13:07.217903'); 
INSERT INTO car_store(car_name, car_time) VALUES ('awesome', '2021-05-01 18:03:27.217903'); 
INSERT INTO car_store(car_name, car_time) VALUES ('awesome', '2021-05-14 18:03:27.217903'); 
INSERT INTO car_store(car_name, car_time) VALUES ('awesome', '2021-05-12 18:03:27.217903'); 
INSERT INTO car_store(car_name, car_time) VALUES ('awesome', '2021-05-13 18:03:27.217903');
```

### Thing that causes error

I would like add the following code - to calculate `difference_between_weeks`:

```
ROUND(car_count_current_week/(car_count_last_week/100) - 100)
    AS difference_between_weeks
```

I have tried calculating in the columns, I have tried adding another sub query. But I don't seem to be able to calculate the `difference_between_weeks` as it tells me "does not exist" or `ERROR:  division by zero`

### Full SQL that errors

An example of the SQL with the added code that **errors**:

```
WITH last_week AS (
  SELECT COUNT(car_time) as car_count_last_week
  FROM car_store
  WHERE car_name = 'awesome'
  AND car_time >= date_trunc('week', CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 week')
  AND car_time <= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '6 days'
), current_week AS (
  SELECT COUNT(car_time) AS car_count_current_week
  FROM car_store
  WHERE car_name = 'awesome'
  AND car_time >= date_trunc('week', CURRENT_DATE)
  AND car_time <= CURRENT_DATE
)
SELECT car_name,
  date_trunc('week', CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 week') AS start_of_last_week,
  CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '6 days' AS today_but_last_week,
  date_trunc('week', CURRENT_DATE) AS start_of_current_week,
  CURRENT_DATE AS today,
  car_count_last_week,
  car_count_current_week,
  ROUND(car_count_current_week/(car_count_last_week/100)) - 100 AS difference_between_weeks
  FROM car_store
  CROSS JOIN last_week, current_week
  WHERE car_name = 'awesome'
  GROUP BY car_name, car_count_last_week, car_count_current_week
  ORDER BY car_name;
```

### Returned error

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  division by zero
SQL state: 22012
```

I feel like I am close but I also feel this may not be possible?
Any pointers to what I am missing would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why you require a `CROSS JOIN` in this case! They are performance killers!

You can simplify this problem **greatly** by doing the following (and make it more general into the bargain!) - all code below is available from the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0608c09d80a181758d007ff473f6e4e7):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS car_store 
(
     car_id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
     car_time TIMESTAMP(0) NOT NULL,
     car_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY(car_id),
     
     car_date DATE     GENERATED ALWAYS AS (car_time::DATE) STORED,
     car_week SMALLINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (EXTRACT(WEEK FROM car_time)) STORED
);
```

Note the use of the [`GENERATED`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-generated-columns.html) (aka "calculated" or "virtual" fields). PG 12 introduced these, and since you're running 13, we're golden!

PG's implementation only has the `STORED` storage type for the moment, but when the `VIRTUAL` type comes along, it would probably be better in this case - although the fields are a mere 6 bytes (4 for `DATE` and 2 for `SMALLINT`).

I also added data - because 6 records doesn't really give a good foundation for any testing!

Sample:

```
-- Week starting on Mon (19-04) and ending on Sunday (25-04) (poor sales)


INSERT INTO car_store(car_name, car_time) VALUES ('awesome', '2021-04-19 10:01:00');
INSERT INTO car_store(car_name, car_time) VALUES ('awesome', '2021-04-19 10:02:27'); 


INSERT INTO car_store(car_name, car_time) VALUES ('awesome', '2021-04-20 12:12:00');

-- no sales on Tuesday

INSERT INTO car_store(car_name, car_time) VALUES ('awesome', '2021-04-22 17:05:27');
INSERT INTO car_store(car_name, car_time) VALUES ('awesome', '2021-04-22 17:06:00');
INSERT INTO car_store(car_name, car_time) VALUES ('awesome', '2021-04-22 17:07:27'); 
INSERT INTO car_store(car_name, car_time) VALUES ('awesome', '2021-04-22 17:08:00');
..
..  ~ 60 more records snipped...
..
```

What I did then was:

```
SELECT 
  cwk,
  c_name,
  LAG(wk_cnt, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY c_name ORDER BY cwk, c_name) AS last_wk_sales, 
  wk_cnt AS this_week_sales, 
  CASE
    WHEN LAG(wk_cnt, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY c_name ORDER BY cwk, c_name) IS NULL 
      THEN '*** No previous sales for period***'
    WHEN cwk = EXTRACT(WEEK FROM NOW())
      THEN 'Figures week to date'
    ELSE   'Figures valid'
  END AS status

FROM
(
  SELECT 
    car_week AS cwk,
    car_name AS c_name,
    COUNT(cs.car_week) AS wk_cnt
  FROM car_store cs
  GROUP BY car_week, car_name
  ORDER BY car_week
) AS tab
ORDER BY cwk DESC, c_name;
```

Result:

```
cwk c_name  last_wk_sales   this_week_sales   status
19  awesome            16                17   Figures week to date
18  awesome            22                16   Figures valid
17  awesome            12                22   Figures valid
16  awesome     NULL                     12   *** No previous sales for period***
```

Note the use of the LAG() PostgreSQL WINDOW function - these are **very** powerful and well worth getting to know - they will repay time and effort spent learning them many times over... LAG() is perfect for your use case where you wish to compare last week's sales with this week's!

I then added calculations for the percentages:

```
SELECT 
  cwk,
  c_name,
  LAG(wk_cnt) OVER w AS last_wk_sales, 
  wk_cnt AS this_week_sales, 
  CASE
    WHEN LAG(wk_cnt) OVER w IS NULL 
      THEN '*** No previous sales for period***'
    WHEN cwk = EXTRACT(WEEK FROM NOW())
      THEN 'Figures week to date'
    ELSE   'Figures valid - period closed'
  END AS status,
  wk_cnt - LAG(wk_cnt) OVER w AS diff,
  ROUND(((wk_cnt - LAG(wk_cnt) OVER w)::REAL/LAG(wk_cnt) OVER w)*100) AS pc_change
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    car_week AS cwk,
    car_name AS c_name,
    COUNT(cs.car_week) AS wk_cnt
  FROM car_store cs
  GROUP BY car_week, car_name
  ORDER BY car_week
) AS tab
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY c_name ORDER BY cwk, c_name)
ORDER BY cwk DESC, c_name;
```

Result (not formatted, except for last two (new) columns):

```
cwk c_name  last_wk_sales   this_week_sales status      diff     pc_change
19  awesome 16   17 Figures week to date                   1             6
18  awesome 22   16 Figures valid - period closed         -6           -27
17  awesome 12   22 Figures valid - period closed         10            83
16  awesome NULL 12 *** No previous sales for period***
```

So, we have our difference in absolute numbers and the percentage change from the previous week

I also added this:

```
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY c_name ORDER BY cwk, c_name)
```

It's another method for tidying up your SQL - you don't have to put that cumbersome `WINDOW` definition all over the place - just a bit of sugar, but nice to have!

I also took care of the problem @nbk pointed out with the INTEGER division - yes, it can trip people up, but just learn about the issue and move on!

```
  ROUND(((wk_cnt - LAG(wk_cnt) OVER w)::REAL/LAG(wk_cnt) OVER w)*100) AS pc_change
```

I used the `REAL` type instead of `DECIMAL` - from [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL), it's only 4 bytes and accurate to 6 decimal places - I hardly think more than that will be required for this use case. Also, from that page:

> However, calculations on numeric values are very slow compared to the
> integer types, or to the floating-point types described in the next
> section.

You can get rid of the cumbersome `CASE WHEN LAG(wk_cnt) OVER w IS NULL` bits by putting the lot in a sub-query as follows:

```
SELECT 
  *, 
  (TO_DATE(cyr::TEXT || cwk::TEXT, 'YYYYWW') + INTERVAL '3 DAY')::DATE AS "Week starting:"
FROM
(
  SELECT 
...
... body of query snipped - see fiddle - it is the same as above
...
  ) AS tab
  WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY c_name ORDER BY cwk, c_name)
) AS tab2
WHERE last_wk_sales IS NOT NULL -- could also add dates between...
ORDER BY cwk DESC, c_name;
```

You mightn't even need this - if you **always** sell at least one car a week - otherwise, you can `JOIN` with a calendar table as shown [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/290949/34007).

Performance with the sub-query doesn't appear to suffer too much (see fiddle), although I would urge you to test various indexes with your own data and h/ware setup - although, with car sales, the number of records isn't likely to be huge.

Comment: thank you so much for your awesome answer - I am working through it today and really understanding what is going on with my query. Your explanations are great and there is a lot of gold in this reply. Who would of thought data was so much fun :)

Comment: Check out [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f6102b34175df8308796b7d66e66e617) - it's correct and faster... glad you found my answer helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Your error was that Postgres interpreted the column as Integer and performs a [Euclidean division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division), which leads to the zero encountered.

Changing the car_count_last_week to a decimal, will give you the [rational numbers division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics))

```
 (car_count_last_week::decimal/100)
```

fixes the problem

> ```
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS car_store (
>      car_id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
>      car_date  TIMESTAMP,
>      car_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
>      car_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
>      PRIMARY KEY(car_id)
>   )
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO car_store(car_name, car_time) VALUES ('awesome', '2021-05-03 15:28:00.116594');
> INSERT INTO car_store(car_name, car_time) VALUES ('awesome', '2021-05-11 16:13:07.217903'); 
> INSERT INTO car_store(car_name, car_time) VALUES ('awesome', '2021-05-01 18:03:27.217903'); 
> INSERT INTO car_store(car_name, car_time) VALUES ('awesome', '2021-05-14 18:03:27.217903'); 
> INSERT INTO car_store(car_name, car_time) VALUES ('awesome', '2021-05-12 18:03:27.217903'); 
> INSERT INTO car_store(car_name, car_time) VALUES ('awesome', '2021-05-13 18:03:27.217903');
> ```

> ```
> WITH last_week AS (
>   SELECT COUNT(car_time) as car_count_last_week
>   FROM car_store
>   WHERE car_name = 'awesome'
>   AND car_time >= date_trunc('week', CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 week')
>   AND car_time <= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '6 days'
> ), current_week AS (
>   SELECT COUNT(car_time) AS car_count_current_week
>   FROM car_store
>   WHERE car_name = 'awesome'
>   AND car_time >= date_trunc('week', CURRENT_DATE)
>   AND car_time <= CURRENT_DATE
> )
> SELECT car_name,
>   date_trunc('week', CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 week') AS start_of_last_week,
>   CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '6 days' AS today_but_last_week,
>   date_trunc('week', CURRENT_DATE) AS start_of_current_week,
>   CURRENT_DATE AS today,
>   car_count_last_week,
>   car_count_current_week
>   ,
>   
>  CASE WHEN car_count_last_week = 0 then 1
>  ELSE ROUND(car_count_current_week/(car_count_last_week::decimal/100)) * 100 
>  END 
>    AS difference_between_weeks
>   FROM car_store
>   CROSS JOIN last_week, current_week
>   WHERE car_name = 'awesome'
>   GROUP BY car_name, car_count_last_week, car_count_current_week
>   ORDER BY car_name;
> ```
>
> ```
> car_name | start_of_last_week  | today_but_last_week | start_of_current_week  | today      | car_count_last_week | car_count_current_week | difference_between_weeks
> :------- | :------------------ | :------------------ | :--------------------- | :--------- | ------------------: | ---------------------: | -----------------------:
> awesome  | 2021-05-03 00:00:00 | 2021-05-09 00:00:00 | 2021-05-10 00:00:00+01 | 2021-05-15 |                   1 |                      4 |                    40000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=df525125673827e3ac66f0fb84ff9751)*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124286/discussion-on-answer-by-nbk-run-calculation-not-working-in-sub-query-does-not).